# Vim: custom colors with matchadd do not work with autocmd

Tags: vim

I am trying to make a custom highlighting and want to use `matchadd` instead of `match`. Here is a sample of my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * call MyColors()
function! MyColors()
  let &nuw=len(line('$'))+2               " Nicer line numbers
  call matchadd('CursorLineNr', '\%81v')  " Highlight 81th symbol
  call matchadd('ErrorMsg', '.*xx.*')     " xx - red line
  call matchadd('DiffDelete', '.*vv.*')   " vv - green line
  call matchadd('Search', '.*??.*')       " ?? - yellow line
endfunction
```

The function gets called, but no highlight appear. If I call it from the command like via `:call MyColors` it highlights everything as it should, just doesn't work automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Guess what – it works when I launch `vim` and then open file via `:e ~/.vimrc`, not when I open it from the commandline `vim ~/.vimrc`. Go figure...

Comment: `BufWinEnter` is not the silver bullet it seems to be, use `autocmd BufEnter,WinEnter * call MyColors()`.

Comment: As matches are window-local, `WinEnter,VimEnter` should be most appropriate (the latter because the former isn't fired for the first one).

Comment: @Ingo Karkat, Sometimes I just would really appreciate buffer-local alternatives to window-local settings. Like folding. Yes it is nice to have a window-local setting, but I would rather have buffer-local fold settings and use a window-local setting to override if needed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for `VimEnter` suggestions. After experimenting a bit I found this combination to be the most bulletproof:

```
autocmd VimEnter,BufEnter,WinEnter * call MyColors()
```